# Parsing through database table and pulling out unique names

Tags: php, sql

I have a table that is listed like this:

Table name: test

```
|--------------------|
|------Column 1------|
|--------------------|
|John,Raul,Matt,Tyler|
|Tim,Hannah----------|
|Zeke,Brady,Tim,Tyler|
|Elliot,Zeke---------|
|Matt,Andrew,Idda----|
...
```

And I need to get all of those names into a PHP array, without multiple cases of the same name.

Would I be better off getting each unique name via SQL, or should I just pull the column, and then parse through it via PHP?

The final PHP array would look like:

```
$test_array[0]="John"
$test_array[1]="Raul"
$test_array[2]="Matt"
$test_array[3]="Tyler"
$test_array[4]="Tim"
$test_array[5]="Hannah"
$test_array[6]="Zeke"
$test_array[7]="Brady"
$test_array[8]="Elliot"
$test_array[9]="Andrew"
$test_array[10]="Idda"
```

I'm not sure how I would parse each cell in the table. What would you guys do?

Comment: My suggestion is normalise your database so you don't have comma separated lists -_-

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows

Comment: Comma separated items... Don't store data like that, it will only cause you lots of trouble!

Comment: Got it. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I agree it's best to normalize the database. However, given the situation you've described, I would perform the SQL select and use PHP to run through the results.

I'd initialize $results as an empty string:

```
$results = '';
```

Then I'd concatenate each row with $results:

```
$results .= $row;
```

Then I'd use explode() to put all of the names in an array:

```
$all_names = explode(',', $results);
```

Then I'd use array_unique() to reduces the $all_names array to unique values:

```
$unique_names = array_unique($all_names);
```

HTH.